# jquery datatable weird result

Tags: php, jquery

i am using data tables and currently i found it very weird by using the stock serverscript ssp class

this is my code

```
       <?php


// DB table to use
$table = 'cards';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'cardId';


$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'cardname', 'dt' => 0),
array( 'db' => 'clan',  'dt' => 1),
array( 'db' => 'grade',   'dt' => 2),
array( 'db' => 'power',   'dt' => 3)
);

// SQL server connection information
 $sql_details = array(
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => '',
'db'   => 'test',
'host' => 'localhost'
);



require( 'ssp.class1.php' );

echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);

?>
```

from my result

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cardname] => Abyss Freezer [0] => Abyss Freezer [clan] => Shadow Paladin [1] => Shadow Paladin [grade] => Grade 0 / Boost [2] => Grade 0 / Boost [power] => 5000 [3] => 5000 ) [1] => Array ( [cardname] => Abyss Healer [0] => Abyss Healer [clan] => Shadow Paladin [1] => Shadow Paladin [grade] => Grade 0 / Boost [2] => Grade 0 / Boost [power] => 5000 [3] => 5000 )
```

as you can see there are 2 result in the array under [cardname] with another [0] duplicate key inside. not sure what is happening in this case. I even tested out to change the columns dt to the column name instead of using int. no luck as well. this will cause some of my data missing during the list out.

Comment: Have you edited any of the functions inside the SSP class? It looks like `simple` function is not returning data properly.

Answer (score 0):

answered my own question, apparently i will need to encode to UTF 8 in order to prevent this issue.